# How to iterate over a C array in inline assembly?

Tags: arrays, c, x86-64, inline-assembly

I just started learning assembly for a contest and I am using `intel-syntax` inline assembly.

Recentlly I've learned how to access global `C` variable's in assembly using `<type> ptr[rip + <variable name>]` syntax. (for example in the `mov` command)

I tried to do the same thing with arrays and by adding a `+ <n * size of one element>` after the variable name, I can access the nth element of the `C` array.

But I decided to write a program that iterates over an array and calculate the sum.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long array[10];

int main()
{
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 1;
    array[2] = 1;
    array[3] = 1;
    array[4] = 1;
    array[5] = 1;
    array[6] = 1;
    array[7] = 1;
    array[8] = 1;
    array[9] = 1;

    unsigned long long element_len = sizeof(*array);
    unsigned long long len = sizeof(array);

    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    
    asm(R"(
        .intel_syntax noprefix;
        
        mov rcx, 0;
        mov r8, 0;
        loop:
            add rcx, qword ptr[rip + array + r8];
            add r8, rax;

            cmp r8, rbx;
            jb loop;
        
        .att_syntax noprefix;
        )"
        
        : "=c" (sum)                    // outputs
        : "a" (element_len), "b" (len)  // inputs
        : "r8" // clobbers
        );
    
    printf("%llu\n", sum);
    
    return 0;
}
```

But because of that `+ r8`;  the compiler gives me this error (works fine when there is some constant value instead of `r8`)

```
$ gcc sum.c
sum.c: Assembler messages:
sum.c:61: Error: `qword ptr[rip+array+r8]' is not a valid base/index expression
```

I am using Kubuntu (technically Ubuntu) 20.04 on a 64-bit Intel processor and compiling the program using `gcc 9.3.0`.

EDIT:
Fixed by @Jester's comment.

```c
asm(R"(
        .intel_syntax noprefix;
        
        mov rcx, 0;
        mov r8, 0;
        lea rdx, [rip+array];
        loop:
            add rcx, [rdx+r8];
            add r8, rax;

            cmp r8, rbx;
            jb loop;
        
        .att_syntax noprefix;
        )"
        
        : "=c" (sum)                    // outputs
        : "a" (element_len), "b" (len)  // inputs
        : "r8" , "rdx"// clobbers
        );
```

Comment: As the assembler said, `[rip+array+r8]` is not a valid address. Consult a manual about what the accepted forms are. TL;DR: if you want `rip` relative, you can only have a displacement. You might do something like `lea rdx, [rip+array]` before the loop and then `add rcx, [rdx+r8]`

Comment: OT, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. Use `sizeof *array` (or `sizeof array[0]`) and `sizeof array`.

Comment: Another tip is that it is best to use [local labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/as/Symbol-Names.html) in inline asm.  If the compiler inlines the function, unrolls a loop, etc, then your asm block may be repeated within the code, and then the label `loop` would be defined multiple times, which is an error.  So you can replace `loop:` with `0:` and then `jb loop` with `jb 0b`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am completely new to assembly but is there any difference between `loop:` and `<some_number>:`?

Comment: Yes there is, see the link I posted.  Having the label `loop:` appear twice in the same asm source file is an error and the assembler will reject it, because when you say `jb loop` the assembler doesn't know which one you mean.  But *local labels* like `0:` are special: you can have many of the same label in the same file, and when you write `jmp 0b` the assembler chooses the closest one that came before the `jmp`, which will always be what you want here.  The `b` is for "back" (you can also write `jmp 0f` to jump to the closest `0` appearing after the `jmp`).

Comment: Thanks! now I can understand it better. I only need assembly knowledge for that little contest and I probably won't continue with assembly. But thanks for the tip!